# What does this line of code do?

Tags: python, parameters

I was just wondering what this line of code does:

`writerow([recordlist[i][0], recordlist[i][1], recordlist[i][2]])`

I know its a parameter of some sort, but what does it actually do in all of this code:

```
 recordlist=[["1",chinese, "male"],["2",indian, "female"]]
 import math 
 import csv
 file_name = 'info.txt'

 ofile = open(file_name, 'a') 
 writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
 for i in range(0,len(recordlist)):
    writer.writerow([recordlist[i][0], recordlist[i][1], recordlist[i][2]])    
 ofile.close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is *not* good code. Whoever wrote this is presumably new to Python.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with `tkinter`.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in `recordlist[i]` and `recordlist[i][0]`, etc.

Comment: you can do the same using `for row in recordlist: writer.writerow(row)` or even `writer.writerows(recordlist)`

Answer (score 0):

You've created a `csvwriter`. It has a method `writerow` that takes a sequence (list, tuple, etc.) of values to write the underlying file in delimited format, which in this case uses a comma as the delimiter. So it will create a row in the csv file for each row in the `recordlist` variable, as it iterates over it in the for loop. Each row will consist of the values defined on the first line of your code, separated by commas.

The real answer should be "run it and try it" to see what it does.

Then read the documentation of the `csv` module in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: If this answered your question, don't forget to upvote and mark it as answered.